# Operator new/delete & destructors

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, destructor

So I'm a beginner trying to get to grips with operator new.  What's wrong with my destructor?

```
class arr{
public:
    arr(){
        pool=::operator new(100*sizeof(double));
    }
    ~arr(){
        ::operator delete(pool);
    }
    void* pool;
};

int main()
{
    arr a;
    a.~arr(); //If I comment this out it's ok.

    void* pool2=::operator new(100*sizeof(double)); //Works
    ::operator delete(pool2); //Fine.

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Leaving a.~arr(); in gives me this error:

Debug assertion failed!  File: dbgdel.cpp line: 52

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

I can't see why pool2 works fine but using the class gives me problems.  Also the error only pops up after the system "pauses", which is after a.~arr() is called???

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, at a glance, you should not be explicitly calling the destructor.  Instead use scoping to force a out of scope and call the destructor.

```
int main()
{
    {
        arr a;
    } //This calls destructor of a

    //Rest of code
}
```

Otherwise the destructor of a gets called twice: once when you call it and again when a goes out of scope.

EDIT:

Here ya go.

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html

Comment: Also read sbi's answer below - you will have problems if you don't declare a copy constructor and assignment operator that ensures multiple copies of an instance of arr don't try to delete the same memory.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you explicitly invoke the destructor on `a` (`a.~arr()`), while ***the destructor will already be invoked automatically*** when `a` goes out of scope at the end of `main()`. When the destructor is called for the second time, it is ***called on an already destructed object***. Technically, this leads to ***Undefined Behavior*** (which is a way to say that any result will be fine according to the C++ standard). In practice this code will likely just execute the destructor again, passing the address stored in the memory location that used to be `a.pool` to the `::operator delete()` (which might or might not be what the constructor stored there), which is caught by the Debug runtime.

What you should do instead if you want `a` to be deleted in the middle of `main()` is to introduce an additional scope:

```
int main()
{
  {
    arr a;
  } //a will be deleted here

  // rest of main

}
```

Another way would be to not to use an automatic object, but a dynamic one, for which you can set a lifetime.

---

But there's ***another problem*** with your code, which you didn't ask about, but which I nevertheless feel a need to point out:

Your class urgently needs a ***copy constructor*** and a ***assignment operator***. (At the very least, declare them `private` in order to disallow copying.) As per the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29), the fact that you need a destructor should give you a hint that the other two are needed as well.
You can avoid all the hassle by not attempting to manually manage dynamically allocated memory. Instead use a type which does this for you:

```
class arr{
public:
    arr() : pool(100*sizeof(double)) {

    }
    // ~arr() // not needed any longer
    std::vector<char> pool;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to call destructor for objects created on stack. The variable 'a' is on stack and will be deleted automatically when out of scope.

Comment: It's not just that you "don't need to"; it's invalid to.